# Issues while export to excel using primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Basically i am new to JSF and primefaces.
i am getting the below exception while performing export to excel in primefaces.

```
javax.faces.FacesException - Cannot find component with expression "dataTableId" referenced from "Export".
```

I dont understand when i have passed the correct id of my datatable to the commandbutton then why it is not able to recognize the component. Please find by below code.

Command Button code:

```
<p:commandButton id="Export" ajax="false" value="Export">    
  <f:facet name="Exporters">                        
   <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="dataTableId" fileName="cars" /> 
   </f:facet>             
    </p:commandButton>
```

Data Table Code

```
<p:panel style="width:800%;height:100%">            
<h:outputLabel value="Search Results" style="font-weight: bold;font-size:14px;"></h:outputLabel>
<p:dataTable scrollWidth="100%" id="dataTableId" var="dataTableId"
value="#{someBean.value}"
selection="#{someBean.value}"
rowKey="#{someBean.id}" scrollable="true" rowSelectMode="multiple" scrollHeight="100%">
```

Is that something i have missed.Any help much appreciated.

Comment: try to mention a full target, like if you have a form or naming container and the datatable is inside it, it should be this  `target=":form:dataTableId"`. or if you don't have any naming container(which I doubt it) reference the component more globally `target=":dataTableId"`. anyway with a bit of google search you could've found the answer.

Comment: i strongly support it and the error that i was getting was because i had written the code for export above dataTable. As you said, if i would have referenced it with form name i could have got it. Thanks for the suggestion. If you can please paste your solution as an answer i can accept the same.